# Change page numbers in MS Word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to change page number of all odd pages to page number of even page before that using VBA in MS 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I get the question. You can use the HEADERFOOTER.PageNumbers object in the word object model to alter the page numbers, but are you wanting the ODD page number to be the SAME AS the even page number?

To do that, I believe you'd need to use a field (NOT the page number field) to calculate the appropriate number and put that in the ODD page number position instead of the actual pagenumber field.

There's a nice description of that here

http://msdn.itags.org/word/64782/